# How to convert yolov8 to application mobile

Tags: android

I use Yolov8 to train the model in google colab and  I export my model to  .tflite and I exucute the project object detection android  tensorflow lite  but when I add my model .tflite to assert it not work   error "Object detector failed to initialize. See error logs for details".Thanks for help me